# Redirect page without onclick wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i'm trying to hard to code some js in wordpress whereby if i type http://test.com/test it'll take me to http://test.com/#test.

I just don't want the user to see the # anchor when pressing the link (from an email or a message).

ideally i thought something like this may work, but i'm clueless..

```
if the link test.com/test 
{
  redirect to (test.com/#test)
}
```

without any onclick or any user input

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: test.com/test refers to the "test" page on wordpress
test.com/#test refers to the anchor "test" on the "home" page

These are two completely different things, and if you redirect in any way, you risk "breaking" the functioning of your site.

Comment: @ThomasLIBERATO ahh, yes that's correct, come to think about it. Even if i use a plugin, is this still bad practice?

Comment: It stills bad pratice whatever you use

Comment: @ThomasLIBERATO so i guess the best thing is to leave everything as it is and not redirect anything.

Comment: Yes this is what I said ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://test.com/test') {
     window.location.replace("http://test.com/#test");
}
```

You can include this in Dom ready function.

Comment: It may makes your site reload again.